# Comparing the last 6th character of the Elements in a List

Tags: python

Pretty New at Python.

I am currently trying to compare the return values of performing a glob.glob method on files in directory but have come to an obstacle in understanding of how to compare the 6th character from the end of each elements in unknown list.

For instance the output of a `Output = glob.glob('Report1.0REV_*.xlsx')`
would return

```
['Report1.0REV_A.xlsx', 'Report1.0REV_B.xlsx', 'Report1.0REV_C.xlsx', etc]
```

But How would I compare the if I appended each file to get A > B, or C > B, or X >Y, then print the latest file?

So far what can think of is writing a for loop with the length of the list but stuck with understanding how i can compare which is greater with the -6 character of each element of the list a then print that file.

```
for i in range(len(Output)):
```

Thank you for reading and your help!

Comment: Are you trying to sort by the 6th last character? Yes, getting the 6th last character is easy, just use `x[-6]` where x is your string.

Comment: Just sort the list. Then  the last element is the largest.

Comment: Well, Robert, care to clarify? You can't expect us to understand what you want if you don't clarify any doubts.

Comment: I agree with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ here, what is the overall goal? To print the file that is larger between the comparisons or to print the largest file in the iterable?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please see [ask]. It is usually good to be explicit about *what output you are expecting*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your answer correctly, you want to fetch the last filename after sorting the list. If this is the case, then the following code might help you. As you say you're new to Python, I've added plenty of comments which might help:

```
# Let's first create a list of unsorted data.
# In this case, (A, C, B) are not in lexicographic order.
unsorted_data = [
    'Report1.0REV_A.xlsx',
    'Report1.0REV_C.xlsx',
    'Report1.0REV_B.xlsx',
]


# The function "pick_letter" will be used later on. It is a very simple
# function comprised of only one statement. That is a very good candidate for a
# "lambda expression". But as you say that you are new to Python, I'll give two
# examples below. One using "lambda", the other using the function
# "pick_letter".
def pick_letter(value):
    '''
    This function takes a value and returns the 6th item from the end. The
    value passed can be anythin that can be indexed, like strings or lists.
    '''
    return value[-6]


# Sorting the input data using "pick_letter"
#
# "sorted" takes an optional argument "key" which holds a function. This
# function will be called for each element in the list and must return
# "something". The list will returned by this "something". In your case, you
# want the 6th element from the end, so we use "pick_letter".
sorted_data_1 = sorted(unsorted_data, key=pick_letter)


# As mentioned above, the same can be achieved by a "lambda" expression. This
# saves us the definition of the "pick_letter" function. Using "lambdas" is
# debatable. They have no name, no doc-string and may be harder to understand.
# But this case is *so* simple that it really is a prime candidate for a
# lambda:
sorted_data_2 = sorted(unsorted_data, key=lambda x: x[-6])


print('Unsorted data:', unsorted_data)
print('Sorted data (using pick_letter):', sorted_data_1)
print('Sorted data (using lambda):', sorted_data_2)

# Now that it is sorted, you can pick the last element using [-1]:
print('Last element:', sorted_data_1[-1])


# Apart from sorting, we can create a new list containing only the 6th
# character from the end for each element. The code below is a so called
# "list comprehension". It is a Python feature which allows you to quickly
# create lists (and other similar collections) from other iterables. In
# this case, the list will have the same ordering as the input 
# (unsorted_data)
characters = [filename[-6] for filename in unsorted_data]
print('Characters:', characters)
```